# Creating a local git mirror from a supergit

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm currently working on this supergit (a git repo with submodules) located in the USA that takes around 40 minutes to clone.
The need has arise to create a local mirror of that repo in order to reduce the cloning time.
Paths of the submodules are relative to the supergit and there are multiple branches, some having more submodules than others.

I made a script that parses all submodules and their relative paths and clones each submodule into the correct place but that works only for one branch (I have to repeat this for every branch an that's where I became stuck).

Is there a way to clone this supergit in a clean way?

Comment: clone is a whole-repo operation, so when you clone the submodule at all you're getting all its branches.  So I don't see why you think you "have to repeat this for every branch".   What, specifically, are you doing on those other branches that doesn't work and so causes you to believe more cloning is necessary?

Comment: Let's say I created the mirror. I can clone from my mirror but when I try to do 'git submodule update --init' this fails.
Git submodules update tries to download the data from my_mirror/../relative_repo_pos but they exist only on original_repo/../relative_repo_pos.
That's why I have to get all those repositories by hand and place them in their correct position relative to my_mirror.

Again the problem is that I have to mirror not just one repo, but *all* the repos that the supergit uses. And different branches come with different submodules so that's why I have to repeat this for every branch.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can parse one .gitmodules file the only thing left is to find them all:

```
# collect all .gitmodules definitions into one file
git rev-list --all --full-history --reverse -- .gitmodules \
| sort -u \
| sed s/$/:.gitmodules/ \
| git cat-file --batch \
| sed /^[0-9a-f]/d \
> gitmodules-aggregate

# format as executable commands to build a dedup'd one:
git config -lf  gitmodules-aggregate | sort -u \
| sed "
   s/=/ /
   s/'/'\\''/g
   s/ / '/
   s/$/'/
   s,^,git config -f gitmodules-consolidated ,
 "
```

Check whether upstream has given different definitions in different commits.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm trying this now, but if I'm not mystaking there shouldn't "sed s/^[0-9a-f]/d" have and extra dash?
What do you want to replace that with?

Comment: Whoops, no, there shouldn't be an `s` on that. fixed.